# How to obtain graph feature values for multiple rna sequences at once?

Tags: graph, machine-learning, igraph, bioinformatics

I need to obtain graph feature values (like maybe around 20) for multiple rna sequences at once.

So if I input the file containing rna sequences the output file should contain these 20 features per line for each sequence. I have looked into **[GraPPLE](http://grapple.mpimp-golm.mpg.de/index.html)** but it gives feature values only for one at a time. Similar case for **igraph**.

I have a 500 sequence file for which I need to obtain these feature values and then further training it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at recent articles citing GraPPLE:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2685108/citedby/

Specifically, RNAcon is also graph-based approach:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24521294

Lastly, this review may be of interest:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5153550/